# Does Apple's App Store accept applications which require users to log in?

Tags: ipad, web-applications, cordova, authentication, app-store

I've developed an iPad app using PhoneGap that requires users to log in.

Will Apple approve apps which require users to log in, or do they have policies in place against requiring users to log in?

Comment: There are plenty of banking apps in the App store which absolutely require a log in for most functions.  But it helps if the app does something useful even without logging in (map to the nearest bank, etc.)

Comment: If it is a private app you might consider the [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) or ad hoc distribution.

Comment: ok, but how does the ad hoc distribution? I read that lasts until the end of the MY ACCOUNT DEVELOPER is not it?

IOS Developer Enterprise Program I did not understand if the activity you must register and pay every year or I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to provide a test/demo account for the review team (there's a field for that when you submit the app), but requiring a login shouldn't be a problem – otherwise there wouldn't be a Facebook app, Instagram, etc.

Comment: thanks for the answers!
the app that I do is for a store and use it to 4 people.

so there is the possibility to register if you can not do a login.
in short, is a private app.

I should also make a map, or the contact details of the store to see even if you're not logged in?

Answer (score 1):

You will almost certainly be allowed to require a user login, however there may be restrictions on how you manage users and password. You may very well not know until you receive feedback from Apple.

Be sure to check the parmeters for submitting an app.
 https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/submission/